# How to resume suspended application in Google play?

Tags: android, google-play

Got mail from Google play stating following:

This is a notification that your application, , with package ID , has been removed from the Google Play Store.

REASON FOR REMOVAL: Violation of the intellectual property and impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy. Please refer to the IP infringement and impersonation policy help article for more information.

Your app and/or elements of its listing on Google Play, including title, description, logo(s), or promotional screenshots must not include unauthorized usage of protected works belonging to a third party.
Your app icon and promotional screenshots must not contain images that appear confusingly similar to existing products.

So i fixed it by removing data violating the rights. Now how i resume my app again with new apk i prepared for same application?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about (re)publishing an app, not about programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms, conditions, and procedures of a distribution channel, not programming.